# plot points as a trajectory of tracking from video

Tags: matlab, plot, point

I think this is very easy question for some of you , but I do not have any experience in Matlab !

I am tracking a point in all the frames in video. now I want to plot this points to show the trajectory

I have (x,y) for the points in all frames

how can I plot this ?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried   **plot(x,y)**   ?

Comment: yes , it does not give me what I am looking for ..... 
I want the horizontal axis for the plot is frame numbers.... and the value of the points in space above !!!

Comment: @seereen could you please tell me how to track different points through frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have coordinates `x` and `y`, and a frame number `t`, then `plot3` or `scatter3` can be useful. The latter allows you to color the points according to the frame number, so that if you rotate it that you only see the xy-plane, you can still distinguish the advancement of time.

Thus:

```
scatter3(x,y,t,[],t)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I did not know how to rotate it ?

Comment: @seereen: in the menu, click on the rotate-arrow. Then rotate the graph. Or right-click on it (with the rotate-arrow active) and select your projection.

Comment: @seereen could you please advise how to create trajectories of different points?